# Repositioning elements out of the general flow on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I have I guess what you would call a primary area and a side area (not a general sidebar with unrelated content), such as:

[image]

That is how it is displayed on desktop, however on mobile it would be ideal if they displayed by their numerical importance displayed in the image.

However on mobile we obviously end up with 1,4,2,3.

I have no problems using `flex`, but in this instance I don't think it would help.

1,4 are in one column and 2,3 in another; I know I could put 1 and 2 in their own row and then they would naturally fall under each other on mobile, but if I did that then obviously 3 would have a huge block of whitespace above it because of 1's height.

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/NepJbX

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content col-sm-8">
      <div class="primary part"><span>1</span></div>
      <div class="secondary part"><span>4</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar col-sm-4">
      <div class="side1 part"><span>2</span></div>
      <div class="side2 part"><span>3</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.row {
  border: 4px solid #000;
}

.part {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;

  &:first-child {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  }

  span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

}

.content {

  .primary {
    height: 300px;
  }

  .secondary {
    height: 100px;
  }

}

.sidebar {

  .side1, .side2 {
    height: 200px;
  }

}
```

**Edit:**

I tried to `flex` the whole thing, which worked well when **1** is longer than **2,3** combined:

https://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/ebvXaO

However if **1** is *shorter*, than it becomes a problem as then **4** doesn't begin straight after **1's** content.

https://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/jXBJRd

Is there any way to do what I want to achieve here?

Comment: the [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property might help you here

Comment: @NickParsons Yes, I'm aware of that, but it's not going to help here as you can see from the layout - the items are in different columns.

Comment: You're right about flex not helping you here, but the grid can do it with ease.

Comment: @VXp you are right, I posted an answer following your idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elegant solution can be achieved with grid (as Vxp said), just changing the areas definition.

In the snippet, check the checkbox to activate the style.  But this can be set with a media query, or whatever else you want

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "a1 a23"
                         "a4 a23";
}
input:checked +  .container {
    grid-template-areas: "a1" 
                         "a23" 
                         "a4";
}
.primary {
    grid-area: a1;
}
.side {
    grid-area: a23;
    border: solid 1px blue;
}

.secondary {
    grid-area: a4;
}
.part {
    border: solid 1px red;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="primary part">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ego in hoc resisto; Non enim, si omnia non sequebatur, idcirco non erat ortus illinc. 
  </div>
  <div class="secondary part"><span>4</span></div>
  <div class="side">
    <div class="side1 part"><span>-----------2--------------</span></div>
    <div class="side2 part"><span>3</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting - thanks. Actually haven't used `grid-area` before; is it possible to insert the _secondary _ right after the _primary_ in the code for better information flow or does it have to go like that?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The layout is handled entirely by the areas of the grid.

Comment: Something like that, but can also be done without grid-template-areas and common container.

Answer (score 1):

You could find some tricky css, redesign, use visibility classes, or use javascript to move the content around the page.

1. I always try to avoid getting too 'cute' with layout tricks.
2. Redesign for a nicely flowing mobile first responsive design that doesn't require much rearranging resulting in tech debt.
3. Use some visibility classes - they don't count against your page as duplicate content with regard to SEO but the page size is larger than it needs to be
4. Keep the current start and add some js to move elements around. This can be difficult to wire up and style and you need to debounce correctly to avoid jumpy artifacts of the reflow, and this is also more difficult to maintain.

In a case like this I would be looking at option #3, visibility classes. Just add a copy of blocks 1 and 2 into the main area and hide them with media queries.

https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/VqpRgp

```
&.mobile-only {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 576px ) {
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but my minimal research about this said it may not be a great idea for SEO purposes.

Comment: I'd like to know about that, can you link an article here?

Comment: Through my quick research I found a couple things, but one was related to saying duplicate content was ok for _separate_ mobile sites, but since this isn't the case here I found this: https://moz.com/community/q/duplicate-content-on-a-page-due-to-responsive-version - which sounds like a guy was trying to create a lot of duplicate content on the one page.

Comment: Brett, thank you for that! I don't find this article very convincing, and site audits by semrush and hubspot haven't caught this type of thing as an issue fror me in the past so I'm still not concerned.  Adjusting my answer for future viewers.

Comment: I did some more research and it pretty much confirmed what you said; and whilst the latter link talks more about separate _pages_ with the same content, I'd think if there was any concern with duplicating content on the same page it would be mentioned there - that said, for anyone else reading, what I read was [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52965/duplicate-content-on-the-same-page-seo-ramifications), and [this](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html) straight from Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix, grid plus media queries.

With grid, you could do something like this

```css
body{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "one two"
                         "four three";
    font-size: 3em;
}

.one{
    grid-area: one;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.two{
    grid-area: two;
    background-color:green;
}

.three{
    grid-area: three;
    background-color: red;
}

.four{
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
    <div class="one">
        1
    </div>
    
    <div class="two">
        2
    </div>
    
    <div class="three">
        3
    </div>

    <div class="four">
        4
    </div>
```